# OpenCV2 codec support

Tags: c++, opencv, codec

I am reading in video files with openCV, I use the following simple code to do this.

```
std::string arg = argv[1];
    VideoCapture capture(arg); //try to open string, this will attempt to open it as a video file
    if (!capture.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "Failed to open video file!\n" << endl;
        help(argv);
        system("Pause");
        return 1;
    }
```

I can load and manipulate several videos, but I have problems with others. I imagine this is down to codec issues. I can play the videos using old style win media player, so the codecs are on the system, but I imagine not available in opencv?

Does anyone know what codecs and video format will definitely play on opencv and what is a good option to convert video to these formats?

Many Thanks

Comment: did you mean, which format videos might play with opencv ?
if yes, try with .avi format, they would work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response I have .avi format and thats what won't load so I imagine its a codec issue

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the supported codec of OpenCV is dependent on your platform and avaible codecs.

This tutorial [Creating a video with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html) explains the video codec of OpenCV clearly. Though it is meant for writing videos, I think the underlying principle is the same with reading videos.

The function `C++: double VideoCapture::get(int propId)` can retrieve your loaded video's codec property by setting `propId = CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC`. The interpretation of FOURCC can be found on this [site](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php). If you have problems with reading .avi videos, it is very likely that the codes is not installed in your platform.